# How to have Clock widgets with multiple timezones

Tags: 20.04, gnome, conky, clock, timezone

I need to have time in multiple timezone displayed either on the top-bar or as a widget on secondary monitor

I'm currently using Gnome clock which requires as click on top bar and times on different zone will be displayed in the pull down menu.

Is there any Conky clock widget that can be configured to display time in timezone which is not the system timezone?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a timezone and offset for a command using the `TZ` environment variable (see `man timezone`). For example, `TZ=NZST-12 date +%H:%M` prints the time in New Zealand, 12 hours east of UTC. In conky you could show this with, for example,

```
 conky.config = { 
  update_interval = 5,
 };
 conky.text = [[ 
  ${execi 10 TZ=NZST-12 date +%H:%M }
]];
```

This runs the command every 10 seconds, so the minutes may change upto 10 seconds late. If you change the 10 to 1, you also need to reduce the `update_interval` to 1 too.